# Gradle pre-dex cache in android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am building same android  project in gradle with little changes in source files. For a clean gradle build it takes Up 5 minutes,

Now I am trying to speed up
I am coping and build it from different directories , So gradle is not hitting cache
I tried to edited the file

```
build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml
```

still no change

### Points i understand

- gradle is using cachce key as absolute path

Is there is any way i can force to use cache .?